# What is the maximum number of rows you can have in a single table database on the Heroku free plan (MongoDB/PostgreSQL)?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, heroku

https://www.heroku.com/pricing

Is there a limit to how big a database you can have on the heroku free plan? Or roughly speaking how many rows the free plan would allow?

Comment: It took me 2 minutes to find this information on the Heroku website. Please do some research on your own before you post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read on the website you linked, a Free PostgreSQL database is limited to 10K (ten thousand) rows.

The [free "Sandbox" MongoDB](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mongolab#pricing) option has no document limit, but a size limit of 496 MB. A single MongoDB document can be anywhere between a few bytes and 16MB.

Comment: Thanks Phil. Any idea how many rows would fit into a 16MB MongoDB document?

Comment: @NilesTurner No, because that depends on the size of your "rows". For details about how MongoDB stores data on the byte-level, check http://bsonspec.org